# bash for loop in python crashed

Tags: bash, for-loop

I`m trying to run a bash loop using a python script.
The command is:

```
python blast2gff.py -b file.blast > file.gff3
```

So, I wrote the following loop to access all my .blast files.

```
for i in *.blast; do "python blast2gff.py -b $i > $i.gff3"; done
```

But I for that error:

> python.cmd: line 1: python blast2gff.py -b KP860292.1.blast > KP860292.1.blast.gff3: command not found

Whats I`m doing wrong?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Drop the quotes. You want to run `python` with a number of arguments, not a program with a name that looks like a command line.

Comment: Removing the `python` tag, as the fact that you are running a Python script isn't relevant.

Comment: `for i in *.blast; do python blast2gff.py -b "$i" > "${i%.blast}.gff3"; done`

Comment: The "line 1" in the error message makes me suspect that you probably don't run bash at all  Please do in your script a `echo version=$BASH_VERSION` just before the and let us know what output you get from it.